# how to extract data using Xpath in Vba

Tags: vba

i want to extract table data from each rows, but it doesn't work.
it work when i change tr to tr[2], else extract only blank value

```
Dim driver As New WebDriver
Dim Url
Dim Rows As WebElements
Dim Value as Webelement

Set Rows = driver.FindElementsByXpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr")
cnt = 1

For Each Value In Rows

Range("a" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[8]").Text 
Range("b" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[7]").Text
Range("c" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[10]").Text
Range("d" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[11]").Text
Range("e" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[18]").Text
Range("f" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[19]").Text
Range("g" & cnt) = Value.FindElementByXPath("td[20]").Text

cnt = cnt + 1

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim col_n as long
for i = 1 to NumCols
if Cells(1, i).Value = "column header you are looking for" Then col_n = i
next

for i = 1 to NumRows
Cells(i, col_n).Value = "PHEV"
next i